# Conditional formatting for treeview in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I am new to WPF and need some help figuring out how to do conditional formatting for a treeview. I have managed to create a tree displaying servers, and each server has clients as child objects. But how can I adjust the code so that a variable changes the actual text and color? F.ex. if IsConnected == false, then Text="Client is disconnected" with Foreground="Gray"? Thanks...

```
        <TreeView>
        <TreeView.Resources>
            <HierarchicalDataTemplate ItemsSource="{Binding Servers}" DataType="{x:Type Objects:SiteViewModel}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/Resources/server.png" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ServerName}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
            <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type Objects:SiteViewModel+Clients}">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Image Source="/Resources/client.png" Margin="0,0,5,0" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ClientName}" Foreground="Green" />
                    <TextBlock Text=" Client is connected: " Foreground="Black" />
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding IsConnected}" />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </TreeView.Resources>
    </TreeView>
```

Comment: Check how you can apply `Style` with `DataTrigger`

Answer (score -1):

I had tried to use Style DataTrigger on the TreeView, but that was a dead end. However, the solution was to use DataTrigger on the TextBlock inside the TreeView. Thanks for the tip.